# log4net does not work in client pc

Tags: vb.net, vsto, log4net

I've problem with log4net where it doesn't work in client pc but in my development pc it can create and write to the log file.

My VSTO add-in is using log4net (installed log4net package using NuGet). So inside my add-in ribbon code, I've added the following code :

Ribbon.vb

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch:=True)> 

<Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(True)> _
Public Class WordRibbon
Implements Office.IRibbonExtensibility

Private ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI
Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

......
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{MyDocuments}\MyApp\AddInLog\WordAddin-log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

When I ran MS Word in my development PC (either debug from Visual Studio 2013 OR directly ran MS Word), log4net will be able to create the logfile inside MyDocuments folder.

But when I ran the add-in inside a clean virtual machine, there's no log file created. THere's no error prompted. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where are you initializing log4net?

Comment: @stuartd before the WordRibbon class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problems in [vsto 4.0 sp1 will cause a VSTO Addin to not find its config file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file/) link.

Difference is in my case, the add-in can be loaded properly and it's working. It just the log4net somehow didn't work.

### Before:

In the add-in registry, the Manifest value will be something like

> Manifest="C:\Program Files\MyApp\WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"

### After:

In the blog, the writer suggested for below changes.

> Manifest="file:///C:/Program Files/MyApp/WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"

And I think that's the reason why log4net can work in my development pc, because Visual Studio use the same URI format for the Manifest value.

But for my case, I tried below and it can also work.

> Manifest="C:\Program Files\MyApp/WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"

I use this URI because in my app, during installation the addin registry value path will be created based on users selection. If I want to change it to file:///, this will involved a few different files (not just the add-ins), so for now this is my solutions.
I'm not sure if using this format can cause any problem.

Comment: I don't know who you are, I don't know where you are, but if I find you, I'll buy you a beer!